# É possível usar o firebase em computadores?

Tags: firebase, aplicação-desktop

preciso criar uma aplicação para controle de finanças personalisado para a empresa que trabalho e queria saber se é possível através de algum mecanismo criar um banco de dados no firebase para ser utilizado em android, web e pc, de forma integrada e em tempo real.

Pergunto sobre o pc, porque não eu quero utilizar o web o tempo todo (dependendo de internet), pois quero na verdade, utilizar no modo offline também em todos os dispositivos para uso em estimativas e geração de relatório.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Já vi a API JavaScript. Não lembro muito, mas é usada em browsers. Ajuda?

Comment: Voce consgue integrar firebase tanto em node como em java e ambas voce consegue fazer todos os tipos de aplicações que voce sitou acima.

Comment: @MarlonJhow Essa integração com o Java, você poderia me dá uma dica para que eu pudesse iniciar os estudos, pois quando procurei um tempo atrás so encontrei para android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce consgue integrar firebase tanto em node como em java e ambas voce consegue fazer todos os tipos de aplicações que voce citou acima.

Segue um exemplo de aplicação java com FireStore ("Novo Firebase"):
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/firestore

Comment: Vlw, ótima dica. Uso furebase mas ainda não tinha visto esse Firestore. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Considere criar a sua aplicação em [Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/br/products/delphi), ele consegue interagir um banco de dados Firebase local e remotamente, além disso através do framework [Firemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireMonkey) você pode criar e importar sua aplicação em diversos formatos p/ desktop e mobile.

---

Segue um exemplo do quão fácil é trabalhar com bancos de dados Firemonkey no Delphi:

- Coloque a [dll](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/) correspondente a versão do seu banco na pasta do seu `.exe` ou em algum PATH listado no seu S.O. (ex. \SYSTEM32)
- Abra sua aplicação e arraste o componente `TFDConnection` da sua janela de ferramentas
- Clique 2 vezes e coloque as especificações do seu DB (Database path, username, password, etc...)
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Arraste o componente `FDQuery` e com ele você pode fazer as chamadas através de query's sql.
  Exemplo:

`FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from tab where code = :Code';
 FDQuery1.ParamByName('code').AsString := '123';
 FDQuery1.Open;`

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas eu gostaria de uma alternativa em java ou python, paranão ter que aprender uma linguagem nova, pois estou sem tempo para tal. Grato!